# No .gz file created after MikTex/TexWorks update, Synctex fail

Tags: texworks, forward-inverse-search

I updated my copy of TeXworks to version 0.4.6 recently, and updated my Miktex at the same time. Since then, it's stopped creating `.gz`-files, so `synctex` no longer works.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the source brings the PDF preview to the front, but doesn't find the corresponding location in the document. Trying the reverse (pdf -> source) results in error:

`"Cannot read file '[file path without filename]'. Access denied."`

There's nothing but plain letters and numbers in the filename and path, and it fails on all documents, regardless of whether the path includes spaces. I created the following document, which still failed to sync, so it's not anything in the content or package clashes:

```
\synctex=1
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}
 anybody home?
\end{document}
```

PdfLaTeX vs XeLaTex doesn't make a difference. I'm using Windows 8.1. Older documents with `.gz`-files from before the update work fine. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: has there been an error message during the updates? what do the log files to MiKTeX say? same for TeXworks.

Comment: @naphaneal No errors or even warnings in the log file after I compile, nor any error messages during TeXworks installation. The system log files from installation are long gone, unfortunately, due to a disk cleanup.

Comment: Have you tried different editors such as TeXmaker?

Comment: TeXmaker doesn't output a .gz file but does successfully jump between source and output.

Comment: I had a friend look at it, and it looks like the `$synctexoption` argument isn't getting passed over when the doc compiles. He came up with a hacky solution: In the Tool Configuration screen (Edit > Preferences >  Typesetting) for each compile method (PdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, etc), remove the `$synctexoption` item, then add `-synctex` followed by `1`, and move `$fullname` to the bottom of the list. Doesn't fix the root of the problem, but it makes synctex happen.